# Using datamaps, I am trying to create a color for each department

Tags: javascript, datamaps

I'm using datamaps (http://datamaps.github.io/) and trying to make a color for each department that have an interval according to the if condition in a France map.

For example if interval == "1-50" make a red color for all the departments that are in this interval, and add this to

```
data: {
    "mydepartment1": {
      fillKey: "red",
    },
    "mydepartment2": {
      fillKey: "gt50",
    }
  }
```

**This is my js :**
import departement_list from "../data/departements-list.json";

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(departement_list));
const dataValues = jsonData.map((data) => data.Departement);
const uniqueValues = [...new Set(dataValues)];

let interval,
nb_votes = [];
for (const valeur of uniqueValues) {
  nb_votes = dataValues.filter((v) => v == valeur).length;
  if (nb_votes <= 0) {
    interval = "defaultFill";
  } else if (nb_votes > 1 && nb_votes < 50) {
    interval = "1-50";
  } else if (nb_votes > 51 && nb_votes < 100) {
    interval = "51-100";
  } else if (nb_votes > 101 && nb_votes < 150) {
    interval = "101-150";
  } else if (nb_votes > 151 && nb_votes < 200) {
    interval = "151-200";
  } else if (nb_votes > 201 && nb_votes < 300) {
    interval = "201-300";
  } else if (nb_votes > 301 && nb_votes < 400) {
    interval = "301-400";
  } else {
    interval = "401-";
  }
}

var map = new Datamap({
  scope: "fra",
  element: document.getElementById("map-france"),
  responsive: true,
  fills: {
    defaultFill: "#EDE8D6",
    "1-50": "#F4F1E6",
    "51-100": "#EDE8D6",
    "101-150": "#E2DABF",
    "151-200": "#CEC191",
    "201-300": "#BCAE7C",
    "301-400": "#9D893E",
    "401-": "#827131",
  },
  data: {
    "mydepartment1": {
      fillKey: "101-150",
    },
    "mydepartment2": {
      fillKey: "151-200",
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is your `departements-list.json`

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's not clear what your code is meant to do, interval never seems to get used and just get's reset with each iteration of `uniqueValues`

I've looked up how to use datamaps it looks like the fill "key" corresponds to
the `fillKey` in the `data` parameter

so for

```
data: {
    "mydepartment1": {
      fillKey: "red",
    },
    "mydepartment2": {
      fillKey: "gt50",
    }
  }
```

To work you would need

```
fills: {
    defaultFill: "#EDE8D6",
    "red": "#F4F1E6",
    "gt50": "#EDE8D6",
  },
```

I found [this](https://david-mohr.com/blog/custom-map-in-javascript) blog post that goes into it in more detail. Hopefully that puts you on the right path

Comment: hello, yes i already checked this link, i didn't find what im looking for